# Finding the interval of convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(\ln (n))^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, divergent-series, absolute-convergence

I have to find the interval of convergence of the following power series:
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(\ln (n))^2}$$

My approach to the problem:

I start by using the ratio test:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg|\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}\bigg|$$ $$ = \lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg|\frac{x^{n+1}} {(\ln (n+1))^2} *\frac{(\ln (n))^2}{x^n}\bigg|$$ $$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg(|x| * \bigg(\frac{\ln (n)}{\ln(n+1)}\bigg)^2\bigg)$$ $$= \lim_{n \to \infty}\bigg(|x| *\bigg(\frac {n+1}{n}\bigg)^2\bigg) = |x|$$

By the ratio test, we know that the given series converges when $|x| <1$. However, the ratio test remains inconclusive when $|x| = 1$. We have to consider the cases where $x = \pm 1$.

When $x = 1$, we have that the series become: $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} {\frac{1}{(\ln (n))^2}} $

When $x = -1$, we have that the series become: $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^n}{(\ln (n))^2}}$

I have no idea how to determine the convergence of these two series. I tried the limit comparison test with $1/x$, but end up getting $\infty$, which does not mean anything. Any help on determining such series would be highly appreciated.

Comment: For $x = -1$, think Leibniz. For $x = 1$, a simple comparison shows whether it converges or not.

Comment: As in the previous comment, you can use the Alternating Series Test for the second series, and your work for the first series shows that it diverges by the LCT since $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

Comment: cool! i'll try it now

Comment: @user84413 okay, just to make sure: the first series diverges by LCT, since $\sum 1/n$ diverges and $1/n < 1/(\ln(x))^2$ for all $n >= 2$. The second series converges by the AST. So, the interval of convergence is $[-1,1)$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.  (For $x=1$, you can either use the inequality you stated and the Comparison Test, or use the limit you calculated and the Limit Comparison Test.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have for all $0\le a<1$

$$\frac {a^n}{\ln^2n}=_\infty o\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$
and the Riemann series $\sum\frac1{n^2}$ is convergent so $R\ge1$. Moreover for $a=1$ we have

$$\frac1{\ln^2n}\ge\frac1n,\quad \text{for $n$ large enough}$$
and the harmonic series $\sum \frac1n$ is divergent so $R\le1$ hence $R=1$.